# how to quantify the strength of trend in univariate time series data?

Tags: time-series, trend, univariate

I have data that looks something like this:

```
  Quarter        Quantity
  Q1-2016       8900.48904
  Q2-2016       8783.1
  Q3-2016       9019.434515
  ..
  ..
  Q3-2019       11000.12
  Q4-2019       11349
```

How do I quantify the growing or falling trend by time(or quarter) using any statistical test.

Comment: Model the mean as a function of time, like in linear regression, and test for the inclusion of the parameter.  For instance $\mbox{E}[y_i] = \beta_0 + \beta_1 t_i$, where $y_i$ is quantity and $t_i$ is time for observation $i$.  In this case, test if $\beta_1 =0$.  Perhaps you could use a more refined variance-covariance matrix instead of assuming independent and identically distributed errors as in linear regression.

Comment: "Model the mean as a function of time" does linear regression accept time as input? to be able to do "E[yi]=β0+β1ti", i don't know how to pass time and moreover i don't have plain time like 03:00, 11:00, but some other form of time(quarters) which is a mix of strings and numbers as shown above. and if i do find a way to model my time component, do i check if the co-efficient for time is 0? and i don't know what "more refined variance-covariance matrix" mean as well. I am a DS practitioner. more a python guy.

Comment: You make a numeric variable for time out of your categorical input, respecting the spacing between categorical inputs.  In this case they are equally spaced, so you could say Q1-2016 is $t_i=0$, Q2-2016 is $t_i=1$, etc.  And yes, you test if the coefficient is zero, but looking at a scatter plot you can also code different functions of time if for instance a nonlinear trend is apparent.

Comment: thanks @user277126, i have two questions: 1. what does β being 0 proves? and 2. how will linear regression modelled this way help me in quantifying the trend? i mean, take pearson’s correlation coefficient, the value closer to 0 implies weaker positive linear relationship, while value close to 1 implies stronger positive. will it be possible to quantify trend this way with linearly regression modelled with x as time encoded as equally spaced numbers in the way you mentioned above and y being my quantity.

Comment: and please elaborate “you can also code different functions of time if for instance a nonlinear trend is apparent.”

Comment: Suppose the mean depends on time linearly, then we should be able to model it as $\mbox{E} \left[y_i\right] = \beta_0 + \beta_1 t_i$.  A scatterplot should show a pattern of points lying on a straight line with some random spread.  Now if $\beta_1 = 0$, then the mean function would only contain $\beta_0$, a  horizontal line.  Hence, testing for this single parameter in OLS is equivalent to testing for a linearly effect in time.  If we had, $\mbox{E} \left[y_i\right] = \beta_0 + \beta_1 t_i + \beta_2 t_i^2$, a quadratic term in time, we could test if both $\beta_1$ and $\beta_2$ are 0

Comment: Testing for the significance of these terms is closely related to pearson's correlation coefficient

Comment: thanks @user277126, i found it here too. https://www.dummies.com/article/business-careers-money/business/accounting/calculation-analysis/how-to-estimate-a-trend-in-a-time-series-regression-model-145940